VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode | Using string
Here there is a really simple contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.25;

contract TestContract {
  string public name;
  uint public number;
  
  constructor() {
    number = 1;
    name = "Normal name";
  }
}

That's my test file:
import ganache from "ganache";
import { Web3 } from "web3";

import { abi, evm } from "../compile.js";

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

let accounts;
let testContract;

describe("TestContract Test", () => {
  it("should read the value of names state variable", async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    testContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
      .deploy({ data: evm.bytecode.object })
      .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "10000000"});  

    const name = await testContract.methods.name().call();

    console.log(name);
    
  });
});

That's my damn output:
1) TestContract Test
       should read the value of names state variable:
     CallError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
      at Blockchain.simulateTransaction (node_modules\ganache\dist\node\1.js:2:100650)

When I try to call the number() method, it works normally. It's only when I try to retrieve a string variable or array of string that the error pop up. It looks like a very simple task, but I don't really know where I'm wronging.
My dependecies:
"dependencies": {
    "ganache": "^7.9.2",
    "mocha": "^10.4.0",
    "solc": "^0.8.25",
    "web3": "^4.1"
  }


instead of using call can you try send. because call can call only view functions. if your abi did not add view to that method, you might be getting this error

The public state variables automatically generates getter functions for them, but just in case, I've already tried to create a getName method but unsuccessful. I printed my abi on console and the methods are there, typed as view.

what truffle version r u using? it is most likely abi issue

I'm using Ganache 7.9.2

Downgrade to Solidity 0.8.19.
8.20 upwards caused compatibility issues.
Also, try to migrate to Ethers and the Hardhat suite. It's more well maintained.
